# Assign the FeaturedViewController as RootViewController in Storyboard

Tags: ios, view, root

I'm new to X-code and app building and attempting at creating a basic app.  I received some pointers from great people.  I have an app that originally loads a screen that shows latest items however I am trying to change so it shows Featured Items instead.  Someone told me that I need to assign the featuredviewcontroller as the rootviewcontroller in storyboard.

Im confused what steps I need to take being a new person to all of this.  Thanks eveyrone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered through email. The app was setup with a navigation controller as the initial view controller. The answer to this question was to set the featured item view controller as the navigation controller's root view controller.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately that did not work.  No other view controller is set to it either.  any other tips?

Comment: Can you post a zoomed out picture of your storyboard? Or message it to me privately?

Comment: What's the easiest way to pm you?

Comment: no email in your profile, think it is private.  send me one to getfowndy@gmail.com